wavesurfer spectrogram not being scaled properly when height is set
The spectrogram and frequency label are not scaled or matched properly when I set the height to a specific value(see the first image). As you can see in the first image, the spectrogram stops between 11khz and 13khz even though it's supposed to be scaled up to 22kz.

let spec = Spectrogram.create({
        container: '#spectrogram',
        labels: true,
        height: 500, // commenting out this line gives the first image
        frequencyMin: 0,
        frequencyMax: 22000,
        labelsBackground: '#919191B3'
      })

I still get a correct-looking spectrogram with the frequency label when I remove the height (see the second image). It's using Wavesurfer 7.7.1

When setting a higher height value I expected to get something that looks like this but maybe bigger
Has anyone encountered this issue?

Just add a sampleRate to wavesurferRef.current.
If you're using React, you can do it like this:
wavesurferRef.current = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: waveformRef.current,
        url: audioUrl,
        height: 0,
        sampleRate: 30000, // adjust sample rate
        plugins: [
          SpectrogramPlugin.create({
            container: '#spectrogram',
            labels: true,
            height: height,
            splitChannels: true,
            frequencyMin: 0,
            frequencyMax: 12500
          })
        ]
      });

